# SocketServer Always Throws BindException for Dynamic Ports

Tags: java, windows, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

> **Definitions**
>   *Well-known Port*
>     Port number in the range [0, 1023]
>   *Registered Port*
>     Port number in the range [1024, 49151]
>   *Dynamic Port*
>     Port number in the range [49152, 65535]

I am attempting to create a `SocketServer` object.  When I allow `SocketServer` to select a dynamic port (by binding to port 0), it works as expected.  If I explicitly specify a registered port, it works as expected.  However, when I specify a dynamic port, it is always throwing a `BindException` with the message "*Address already in use: JVM_Bind*".  The top of the stack trace for the exception is:

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
```

I am using JDK 1.8u74 on a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64 machine.  The code is as follows:

```
SocketServer createServer(final int port) throws IOException {
    // Create a new socket server
    SocketServer server;
    try {
        // Try to bind to all interfaces
        server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, null);
    } catch (BindException e) {
        // If that fails, try to bind to the primary IP address
        final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, address);
    }
    return server;
}
```

I have also tried the following alternative:

```
SocketServer createServer(final int port) throws IOException {
    // Create a new socket server
    final SocketServer server = new SocketServer();
    server.setReuseAddress(true);
    try {
        // Try to bind to all interfaces
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port), 1);
    } catch (BindException e) {
        // If that fails, try to bind to the primary IP address
        final InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), 1);
    }
    return server;
}
```

Both of these alternatives throw a BindException when `port` is a dynamic port.  I have verified that all of the roughly 50 dynamic ports I tested are available according to the results of `netstat -an`.  Is there any way to create a `SocketServer` for a specific dynamic port?

Comment: I suggest you trace the value of `port`. This kind of code works for everybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal since it involves registry edits, there is an answer provided on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/132007).

Windows can be setup to exclude ports from its range of dynamic ports.  Simply add the range(s) to exclude to the Multi-String value:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Parameters\ReservedPorts

So, in my case I have a requirement to use ports 55101-55107, so I added that text to the registry value and restarted the computer.  While this solution allows me to use those ports, it is disappointing that I have to edit the registry on any Windows machine where I want to use them.  In addition, if I have to add another dynamic port in the future, I will have to re-edit the registry.